# full width images slider

Tags: html, image, css, slider

I'm trying to do a full width slider from scratch but i got stuck at the moment to put images width to 100%

I have a slider is 100% width and overflow: hidden, inside an ul is 10000px width. That's why I can not put images 100% width. Please help!
here is my [pen](http://codepen.io/aprendizfc/full/MyRRRR/%22pen%22)

```
<div id="slider" class="slider">
  <ul class="content-slides">
    <li class="slides">
      <img src="img1.jpg" alt="">
      <div>
        <h1>lorem ipsum dolem</h1>
        <p>paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="slides">
      <img src="img2.jpg" alt="">
      <div>
        <h1>lorem ipsum dolem</h1>
        <p>paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="slides">
      <img src="img3.jpg" alt="">
      <div>
        <h1>lorem ipsum dolem</h1>
        <p>paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="slider_nav"></div>
</div>
```

here is my css

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    /*width: 600px;*/
    /*height: 300px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.slider .content-slides {
    width: 10000px;
}
.content-slides .slides {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.content-slides img {
    width: 100%;
}
.content-slides div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
    color: #fff;
}
#slider_nav {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 40%;
    right: 10px;
}
#slider_nav li {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#slider_nav li span {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#slider_nav li span.active {
    background: #fff;
}
```

any help is going to be appreciated

Comment: there is no device to view an image that large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use viewport height and width. I have created a [code pen](http://codepen.io/shashanktrivedi0728/pen/EKJzLZ). Hope it works for you.

```
.slider .content-slides {
    width: 300vw;
}
.content-slides .slides {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.content-slides img {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

In JS -

```
'margin-left': -(pos * Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) )
```